# Resolution of Singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Consider $y^8=x^{11}$.

So, $y^8-x^{11}=0$.

Define $f(x,y)=y^8-x^{11}$.

Then, $\nabla f = (f_x,f_y)=(-11x^{10},8y^7)$.

For $(f_x,f_y)=(0,0)$, we must have $(x,y)=(0,0)$; the singular point.

How do I go about resolving the singularity using blow ups? Are there any books with worked out examples?

Comment: Quick answer: substitute $xy$ in place of $y$. Divide out the highest power of $x$ that you can, and look at what's left over. Repeat until you get a smooth curve.

Comment: As for a book, I think _Singularities of Plane Curves_ by Wall should discuss these kinds of examples in detail. Indeed, the Google Books preview shows that Example 3.4.1 discusses precisely the example you ask about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blow-up is locally given by $(u,v)\mapsto (u,uv)$ and $u=0$ is the exceptional divisor.

Hence, the pull-back of the curve $C$ given by $y^8-x^{11}$ is given by $(uv)^{8}+u^{11}=u^8(v^8+u^3)$. The pull-back is then equivalent to $8E+\tilde{C}$, where $C_1=\tilde{C}$ is the strict transform of the curve, given by $$u^3+v^8$$

Note that another chart for the blow-up is $(u,v)\mapsto (uv,v)$ but this one removes the point corresponding to the direction of $y=0$ so it is not good in your case, as it is exactly where your curve passes through.

The curve $C_1=\tilde{C}$ has a point of multiplicity $3$ with tangent $u=0$. You can then use
$(u,v)\mapsto (uv,v)$ and obtain $(uv)^3+v^8=v^3(u^3+v^5)$ and the second strict transform $C_2=\tilde{C_1}=\tilde{\tilde{C}}$ has equation $$u^3+v^5.$$

Continuing this way you get 
$$u^3+v^2$$
$$u+v^2$$

Hence the sequence of multiplicities is $8$, $3$, $3$, $2$.